# Center align single collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift

I like to center align a UICollectionview cell, if only single cell is returned. I am using this

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if self.imageSelected.count == 1
        {
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
                return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0)
            }
        }

        return self.imageSelected.count

    }
```

The above code is getting selected if the count is one but I am not seeing any movement in the cell location.

I also tried this but here it is not even hitting the breakpoint

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if self.imageSelected.count == 1 {
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0)
        } else {
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.imageSelected.count

    }
```

Comment: This is what a custom collection view layout is for....

Answer (score -1):

Put this into your view controller instead of the code in your question:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if self.imageSelected.count == 1 {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0)
    } else {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

This makes the code that you have created work. If you need a more exact answer on how to center a cell, please ask and I will put some time and effort into helping you out :)

Comment: I did what you told but it doesn't work, it is not even hitting the breakpoints.

Comment: Implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, set the delegate for collection view layout to self

Comment: I did this in viewDidLoad() ,  self.collectionView!.delegate = self; it still doesnt work